# How can I modify the interface for $http in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interface, typescript

In my application call I have code looking like this:

```
            $http({
                url: '/abc'
                method: "PUT",
                ignoreLoadingBar: true
            })
```

It's a normal $http call but there's an added parameter that is added because I am using the angular-loading-bar.

Typescript flags this as an error like this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   TS2345  Argument of type '{ url: string; method: string; ignoreLoadingBar: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IRequestConfig'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ignoreLoadingBar' does not exist in type 'IRequestConfig'.
```

I understand why it shows the error but what I want to do is allow this additional parameter.  I want to do something like this:

```
interface IRequestConfigPlus extends ng.IRequestConfig {
  ignoreLoadingbar: boolean
}
```

Can someone tell me is there a way that I can make it so the $http does not give a typescript error? If possible I would like to fix this without going in and modifying the interface for IResponseConfig that is in the AngularJS code.

**Update**:

Basarat has made a good suggestion but I am still not sure how I could use the interface which is part of my question.  So the question is how can I use IRequestConfigPlus here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me is there a way that I can make it so the $http does not give a typescript error?

Its because of object freshness : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html

Quick workaround : ([use an assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html))

```
        $http({
            url: '/abc'
            method: "PUT",
            ignoreLoadingBar: true
        } as ng.IRequestConfig)
```

## Better fix

Create a `.d.ts` file for angular-loading-bar that adds additional properties to the `angular.IRequestConfig` interface. Note: [TypeScript interfaces are open ended](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/interfaces.html)

Comment: Thank you.  I did try creating a IRequestConfigPlus.d.ts file and the interface is mentioned in the question. But I am not sure how to use that.  I like your idea of the as.ng.IRequestConfig.  Is that the same as if I cast it to <IRequestConfig> by putting that first ?

Comment: Yes ...thats the same

Answer (score 1):

This minimal example works for me:

```
///<reference path="typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

let $http:ng.IHttpService = null;

declare module angular
{
    interface IRequestConfig {
        ignoreLoadingBar: boolean;
    }
}

$http({
    url: '/abc',
    method: "PUT",
    ignoreLoadingBar: true
});
```